# Webcam working for admin, not for standard user Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: webcam, users

I just installed Ubuntu, I've been a longtime Debian user but I'm a bit lost with some things.

My admin account has everything working nicely, I created a standard user account for my wife but I haven't been able to make the webcam work on her account.

I was thinking it had to be something related to the groups, when I ran groups on the admin account I got this:
ale adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Groups for my wife account:
valentina nopasswdlogin

I was kind of expecting my account to have the usual groups (video, audio, etc), but got lost with this info. Any suggestions?

Help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nopasswdlogin breaks a lot of things.

Don't use it for GUI login.

Use the built-in auto-login functionality instead(nopasswdlogin is supposed to be reserved for command-line users and is intentionally broken for GUI users).

[image]

Comment: I changed the my wife's user like you suggested but with no luck. After that I added her to the video group like @Thomas suggested in the answer below and no luck either. Any other suggestions? Thank you for such a quick answer.

Comment: Are you sure you removed her from the nopasswdlogin group and restarted and didn't just turn on autologin?

Comment: Yes. From what I understand regarding groups there's no reboot needed, just to log out and back in. I rebooted anyway and nothing.

`valentina@piemur:~$ groups`    
`valentina video`

Comment: I'll dig in to it in a VM for a bit tonight.  I expect to update the answer or comment 'no dice' tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your are right - this is a question of groups. You need to have the group `video` to use the webcam.

Comment: in a case where I tested this, being in appropriate groups didn't fix some issues (automounting for example).  that's why i recommended not using nopasswdlogin instead of adding video...to stave off future questions.

Comment: My webcam has these rights: `crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jun  9 13:16 /dev/video0`. So from my understanding you have to have the video group to use is. Of course you are right - nopasswdlogin breaks several tings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Thomas, unfortunately neither adding the group or not using nopasswdlogin helped. If you have any more suggestions I appreciate it. Thank you again.